# How to sort array with other arrays by date and take a limit in laravel and carbon

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have this array with other 16 arrays

```
array:16 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1867
    "meta_date" => Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1564536945 {#4600 ▼
      date: 2019-07-31 01:35:45.0 UTC (+00:00)
        }
         "title" => ""
        "summary" => """
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1868
    "meta_date" => Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1524215895 {#4465 ▼
      date: 2018-04-20 09:18:15.0 UTC (+00:00)
    }
    "meta_type" => ""
    "title" => ""
    "summary" => """
```

and so on...

[image]

I want to sort the main array by date specified in "meta_date" field included on each "child" array, the sort can be `$sort= "asc"` or `$sort= "desc"`

and

I want to take a dynamic limit for the main array, for example if `$limit=10` take the first 10 arrays sorted by date selected

currently, I'm using PHP 7.3 and laravel 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) come with everything you need:

```
collect($arr)->{$sort === 'desc' ? 'sortByDesc' : 'sortBy'}('meta_date')->take($limit)->values()->all();
```